# What is the value of the angle $x$ in the given figure?

Tags: geometry

For reference: If $P, Q, M$ and $N$ are points of tangency, calculate $x$ if $\alpha+\theta = 100^\circ$

[image]

My progress:

draw some auxiliary lines to try to verify a solution...
extend $AP$ and $BQA$ until they intersect at $G.$
$\measuredangle G = 80^o\\
\measuredangle MHO_1 = \measuredangle MEO_1$

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw $PN$ and $QN$

$\angle NPQ=\alpha$ (tan-chord)

$\angle MQP=\theta$ (tan-chord)

Let $R$ be intersection of $PN$ and $QM$

$\angle R = 180^\circ - (\alpha + \theta)=80$

$PN=PQ$ (tangents from same point) $\angle QPN = \angle QNP = \alpha$

$PM=PQ$ (tangents from same point) $\angle QPM = \angle QMP = \theta$

In quadrilateral $MRNL$

$180^\circ-\alpha +180^\circ - \theta + \angle R + x =360$

$x=20^\circ$

Comment: I think there is a typo. It should be $R=PN\cap QM$.

Comment: @TheBestMagician thanks,  I edited.